# How to fix device when stuck in firmware update with "Do not disconnect USB" message?

Tags: updates, boot, lg

I have an LG Android phone. When I turned it off last night, it turned itself back on again with the firmware update showing "Do not disconnect USB". But when I received it from my contract holders, there was no USB; so I used my regular charger. I've woken up this morning and it's still on 0% after about 10 hours.

Can someone help or give me any tips and advice?

Comment: It's a fluke... Hold power button until reboot occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Either wait until the battery runs out to recharge it, or wait until the device resets by itself.

This has happened to me twice:

1. The first time, about 3 days, it just reset itself.
2. The second time, after giving up when trying to reset the device by holding down the power and volume down buttons while either plugged or not, the screen suddenly went blank. Then, after plugging-in to charge the device, the screen was unfrozen and it charged up.

It seems to me that on both occasions this has happened, my phone has been almost out of battery, though I don't know if this is related or not. Better to keep the device charged up at all times.

Answer (score 1):

Try holding down the power and the volume down buttons at the same time for around 10 seconds, then the device should restart and run normally again.

I remember with a situation with my iPhone when it got frozen and I had to reboot it with the same approach. This also worked on my Android phone which was stuck on 0% firmware update.